# I installed the Visual Studio 2022 too but still it is not allowing me to yarn install

Tags: node.js, next.js, node-modules, yarnpkg, node-gyp

Is there anyone who can help me with this issue? I cloned the project and I'm trying to install the dependencies to run it. I also installed Visual Studio 2022, while I have Visual Studio Code. It told me that it required C++ development tools. After installing Visual Studio and the latest version of Python, it still does not allow me to install the dependencies. How can I fix this? Is there anyone who can help?

```
PS C:\Users\DELL\Documents\adil-waheed\damngoodtools> yarn install
yarn install v1.22.19
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > react-day-picker@8.7.1" has unmet peer dependency "date-fns@^2.28.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[1/5] ⠄ @prisma/engines
[2/5] ⡀ hnswlib-node
[3/5] ⡀ sharp
[-/5] ⡀ waiting...
error C:\Users\DELL\Documents\adil-waheed\damngoodtools\node_modules\hnswlib-node: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\DELL\Documents\adil-waheed\damngoodtools\node_modules\hnswlib-node
Output:
C:\Users\DELL\Documents\adil-waheed\damngoodtools\node_modules\hnswlib-node>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\nogyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.6 found at "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS running in VS Command Prompt, installation path is:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - will only use this version
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.7.34031.279) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:369:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:390:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:427:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\DELL\Documents\adil-waheed\damngoodtools\node_modules\hnswlib-node
```